# Can ISNULL or IFNULL in h2 strings

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, h2

I am calculating average qty per month and i am using h2 with a query like this

```
SELECT t.truckCode,   
        monthname(orderDate)  as month, 
        IFNULL (avg(petrolQty),0) as avgPetrolQty 
from  
   truck t left join orderz o 
on 
   t.truckId = o.truckId 
group by t.truckCode, monthname(orderDate) 
order by t.truckCode, monthname(orderDate)
```

so i get 0 if avg is null which is good but its a left join i want to use so i can see all trucks in the system. problem is when  truck has never had an order monthname(orderDate) return null , how can i change it to get some default values , i tried ifnull but did not work , i would prefer to return a string eg,not announced

for the query aboove this is my result

```
TRUCKCODE   MONTH   AVGPETROLQTY  
BY2004  null    0.0
BY2354  January 13.0
BY2874  January 13.0
BY2994  null    0.0
BY8754  January 13.0
```

how can i change null to some default string

```
 SELECT t.truckCode,  COALESCE(monthname(orderDate),'Not Announced')  as month,  IFNULL (avg(petrolQty),0) as avgPetrolQty 
from  truck t left join orderz o  
on  t.truckId = o.truckId 
group by t.truckCode, monthname(orderDate)  
order by t.truckCode, orderDate
```

Comment: will this solve the problem of getting null on monthname ?

Comment: no its thesame problemi want to solve the null problem with orderDate

Comment: Can you paste the result of the query changing the monthname part to CASE WHEN(orderDate is null then 'NOT ANNOUNCED' ELSE monthname(orderDate)

Comment: hi i just posted my result for the previous query , can you arrange you query so i can understand it or where to place , im new to some functions @Graciano

Comment: just updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function COALESCE to check if the month is null then use a default value like 'Not Announced'.

```
SELECT t.truckCode,   
        COALESCE(monthname(orderDate),'Not Announced')  as month, 
        IFNULL (avg(petrolQty),0) as avgPetrolQty 
from  
   truck t left join orderz o 
on 
   t.truckId = o.truckId 
group by t.truckCode, COALESCE(monthname(orderDate),'Not Announced') 
order by 1,2;

Result:
TRUCKCODE   MONTH   AVGPETROLQTY  
BY2004  Not Announced 0.0
BY2354  January 13.0
BY2874  January 13.0
BY2994  Not Announced    0.0
BY8754  January 13.0
```

Comment: say order date must be in group by , it seems coalesce hides the group by already written

Comment: Nope. functions in the select statement is done as the last steps. Thus it will not affect the group by clause.

Comment: but for some reason it only works when i add an extra orderDate along the group by , why is that

Comment: i posted it check

Comment: You posted my answer, so what is the result you are getting vs to my answer query?

Comment: you answer yes , i tried you answer and it say i should add orderDate to group by clause

Comment: when i added it worked so my quetion is why does it require something like this goup by monthname(orderDate), orderDate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168063/discussion-between-anxmous-and-valik).

Comment: do you think because of the year and month may be it requires implementation of hierarchy